# Detecting no results in adodb select query

Tags: sql, c, database, adodb

I'm using ADODB connection in C. The code works more or less fine but I'm getting errors when there is no result for my query and I try to read it. Relevant code:

```
__object *con, *rec;
con = __object_create("ADODB.Connection");
if(con!=NULL) con->Open("odbc name"); 
if (con == NULL || con->State==0)
{
    return 0;
}
rec= __object_create("ADODB.RecordSet");

sprintf(query, "SELECT SUM(column) FROM table WHERE %s", constraint);
rec->CursorLocation=3;
rec->Open(query, con, 1, 3);
float result = rec->Fields(0); // <- Error here
rec->Close();
__object_delete(rec);
__object_delete(con);
```

I'm getting error code 80020005 (Type mismatch). The DB column is type float. When there are records that meet the constraint and I get a result everything works fine. But when it matches no records the DB server returns null and I get the error. Fortunately result is set to 0 which is reasonable but I would like to detect this better.

The standard ways (BOF/EOF, Fields->Count, == NULL, ...) all fail. Most code samples I can find are for VB and not C so they are not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`rec->Fields(0).Value` returns a variant, before assigning to the float variable check if the variant represents a VT_NULL which indicates that the data returned is NULL.